# Can Eh Cache handle object version changes?

Tags: ehcache

Let's say I have a Widget in a package version 1.0.
I use eh cache and store tons of these objects in the disk cache.

Two weeks later, someone adds a field to Widget, bumps the package to 1.1, and redeploys.  Can eh cache handle loading the out of date objects from the persistent cache?  Will it be able to ignore missing, or extra fields?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just read Eh Cache utilizes the Serializable interface, so I guess so long as your implementation accounted for potentially missing fields, it would be alright.  hmm.